# How to resolve error run gitlab ci runner (windows)

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am not able to run my python project test using gitlab ci. I am using gitlab public and runner run on my windows machine. I can run .gitlab-ci.yml using share runner on gitlab cicd but failed when I run my own runner.

1. Runner is installed and registered successful in my windows7 (executor-docker,no tag define, default image python:3.6)
2. I can see my windows runner run activated (green) in gitlab cicd and I disabled shared runners
3. My windows is already have docker installed (docker quickstart terminal)

When commit my jobs failed with the following error message

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.0.1 (21cb397c)
   on myhp7runner TKAFPyGA
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:10
 ERROR: Removing network for build
 ERROR: Preparation failed: error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.25/info: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running. (docker.go:1003:0s)
 Will be retried in 3s ...
 ERROR: Removing network for build
 ERROR: Preparation failed: error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.25/info: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running. (docker.go:1003:0s)
```

from MINGW64 CLI

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302

$ net start com.docker.service
The service name is invalid.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185.

$ docker version
Client:         18.03.0-ce
 API version:   go1.9.4
 Git comFri Mar 23 08:31:36 2018
 OS/Arch:       falsews/amd64
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:        19.03.5
  API version:  go1.12.12imum version 1.12)
  Git commit:   Wed Nov 13 07:28:45 2019
  OS/Arch:      false/amd64
 containerd:al: v1.2.10
  GitCommit:            b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:            3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:   0.18.0
  GitCommit:            fec3683
```

```
$ docker-machine env --shell cmd default
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\dz-12NT\.docker\machine\machines\default
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
SET COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=true
REM Run this command to configure your shell:
REM     @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env --shell cmd default') DO @%i
```

Not able to start docker service. How to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Yup..install from DockerToolbox.exe windows7

Comment: how to get the log? docker logs ?

Comment: Are you able to launch manually at least one container ?

Comment: I able to run hello-world

Comment: okay, I could see that gitlab runner unable to access docker daemon

Comment: `docker-machine env --shell cmd default`

execute this and let me know output

Comment: the output updated above

Comment: Im getting the same output sir, $ docker-machine env --shell cmd default
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\dz-12NT\.docker\machine\machines\default
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
SET COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=true
REM Run this command to configure your shell:
REM     @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env --shell cmd default') DO @%i

Comment: In gitlabs , you have to set/export env variables
`DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\dz-12NT\.docker\machine\machines\default
DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=true`

Comment: do u mean in the yml file? Is it normal way of run gitlab ci runner? seems complicated. Is it because runner in windows?

Comment: yes, actually, docker is installed through boot2docker, docker didn't get installed directly on windows machine, its installed in linux(guest os on top of windows)which has ip `192.168.99.100` and serving docker service at `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376`

Comment: ohh...ya...its over virtualbox... do you have sampel yml with the same config that i can use for test... this all new to me... thank you

Comment: No buddy, I don't have. Didn't get chance to work on GitLab,
Install ubuntu in virtualbox, and do stuff, that makes easy

Comment: yup...ok...thanks for your help...really appreciate it.